# Can I give away unused steam games as gifts?

Tags: steam

I got a pack with a couple of games. I accepted the pack, but one of the games I don't want to play, and I never have. Does it work to give only that game back? If it helps; the game is Need for speed Shift 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a trick question. The answer is simply: **No.**

Steam says:

> **What restrictions are there on trading Steam Gifts?**
>
> Trading a Steam Gift is very similar to sending a gift to someone; just that once it is traded that user can then either trade it again, or open it for themselves. There are no restrictions on territory.

A bundle of games or a pack is considered as one game. Unfortunately, you will not be allowed to trade that game or gift it under any circumstances.

[Source](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417#restrictions)

Comment: There are exceptions (such as HL2 and HL2: Episode 1 from the Orange Box bundle), but they are few and far between.

Comment: @Powerlord Thanks, I never heard of such exceptions!

Comment: There's a list of them somewhere on one of Steam's Support pages, but I don't know the link off hand and I can't view Steam pages from here (at work).